# Iterate through java String array and update

Tags: java, arrays, string

Say I have a String array

String arr[] = {"    a", "      b"}

and I want to trim every element in the array. I found this code doesn't work.

```
for (String s: arr) {
    s = s.trim()
}
```

But this works:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].trim()
}
```

What is the reason for that?

Comment: The `String s` that you are using is valid only within that loop. You are creating an entirely new object, and not operating on the actual array.

Comment: In short `for (String s: arr) {...}` is same as `for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++}{String s = arr[i]; ...}`. So it is same situation like `String a = "x"; String b = a; a="y";//what is b?`